# In iOS 14.7.1 app disconnecting from BLE device when writing data in particular characteristic

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, data-transfer, cbcentralmanager

While writing data in BLE device (file size is 459 KB), connection lost happened in between BLE device and application. It's happened particularly in iOS 14.7.1 devices not for older OS (like 14.6). I observe MTU size also different in iOS 14.4 and iOS 14.7.

When disconnection happened CoreBluetooth -> centralManager: didDisconnectPeripheral delegate method call.

Can't figure what's the main issue, 1) issue from BLE end 2) issue for application end 3) issue for OS end

Is any key value should I add in application. What is proper solution for resolve this issue.

Comment: If you are unsure wether your app or the OS is at fault here try to write the particular characteristic using a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) or something similar. If writing works without a disconnect your app might be at fault

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, Application is work till iOS 14.6 and android all devices. Also app store version not working on 14.7. I will try with nRF connect app but for this I need to convert bin file to binary array. any suggestion on same.